# Relation between different $E_8$ matrices

Tags: nt.number-theory, lie-groups, lattices, root-systems, exceptional-groups

There are several rank-8 square matrices known to be related to $E_8$:

1. Cartan $E_8$ matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_(mathematics)#Cartan_matrix

$$M_1=\left [\begin{array}{rr}
 2 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
-1 &  2 & -1&  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 & -1  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 & 0 &  0 &  -1 &  0 &  0 & 2
\end{array}\right ]$$

2. One choice of simple roots of $E_8$ is given by the rows of the following matrix
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_(mathematics)#Simple_roots

$$M_2=\left [\begin{array}{rr}
1&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&-1&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&-1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&-1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&1&-1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&1&1&0 \\
-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&-1&0 
\end{array}\right ]$$

3. $E_8$ lattice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_lattice#Properties

$$M_3=\left[\begin{matrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 1/2
\end{matrix}\right]$$

I have also seen:
$$M_4=\left [\begin{array}{rr}
 2 & 1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
1 &  2 & 1&  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 & 1 &  2 & 1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 & 1 &  2 & 1 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & 1 &  2 & 1 &  0 & 1  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 1 &  2 & 1 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 1 &  2 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 & 0 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  0 & 2
\end{array}\right ],$$
also
$$M_5=\left [\begin{array}{rr}
 2 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
-1 &  2 & -1&  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1  \\
 0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 & -1&  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 2
\end{array}\right ]$$

My question is that

- What are relations between different $E_8$ matrices? $M_1, M_2, M_3, M_4, M_5$ (Of course, they are related to  $E_8$. They are all unimodular.) Could they be transformed to one from another, vice versa? (like $GL(8,\mathbf{Z})$?) What are the meanings of these transformations?

Comment: There are different conventions for ordering of roots, and that might be what is happening here; see https://ctan.org/pkg/dynkin-diagrams for some of the popular conventions.

Answer (score 9):

$M_1$, $M_4$ and $M_5$ are all the same quadratic form up to integer change of basis: To get from $M_1$ to $M_4$, conjugate by the diagonal matrix with digaonal entries $(1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1)$; to get from $M_1$ to $M_5$, conjugate by the permutation matrix $76543218$.

We have $M_2 M_2^T = M_1$, in other words, the rows of $M_2$ realize the quadratic form $M_1$, and the rows of $M_2$ are a basis for the $E_8$ lattice. (This is always the relationship between the simple roots and the Cartan matrix.)

$M_3$ is a matrix whose columns form a basis for the $E_8$ lattice. It is related to $M_2$ by
$$M_3 = M_2^T 
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$
(This matrix has determinant $1$.) Thanks to Dave Benson in the comments for pointing this out. It looks like $M_3$ might be something like the [Hermite normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form) of $M_2^T$; it doesn't exactly match the Wikipedia definition of HNF, but there are many variants on Hermite normal form in the literature.

---

As an overview: the columns of $M_2^T$ and $M_3$ are each bases of the same lattice. The matrices $M_1$, $M_4$ and $M_5$ are Gram matrices of various bases for that lattice -- $M_1$ is the Gram matrix in the columns of $M_2^T$, and the other two come from permuting and switching the signs of those basis vectors.

Comment: The columns of $M_3$ form a basis for the $E_8$ lattice that isn't a set of root vectors. I can't vouch for why it appears on Wikipedia.